# Scroll bar not showing for element with overflow auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why isn't the scroll bar showing y axis for the `item-container` element? It doesn't display the full width for the x axis either. How can I get this element to stretch to `column-2` height and width and display scroll bars for the overflow.

https://jsfiddle.net/cd83mgex/4/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.column-1 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.column-2 {
  flex: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.item-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.6);
}

.item {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 20px;
  background: orange;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column-1">
    column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: should add min-heighgt for .item-container class

Comment: it seem's your fiddle working fine check just because you have horizontal scroll you can see - check scrolling horizontally.

Comment: @Sumit Patel those scroll bars are for the window, not the .item-container element

Comment: @doe check my answer you will see scroll bar for .item-container

Comment: Please include all information relevant to the question, in the question itself, that includes HTML. Please see [mcve]

Comment: see answer below for `Set [max-]width: 50% for .column-2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.item-container` is 100% as wide as it's parent: `.column-2`.
`.column-2`'s largest child element is `.item` which is 2000px and `.column-2` has no width restrictions. Therefore `.column-2` is at least 2000px wide.

There is a scrollbar that is automatically placed on `.item-container` on the far right but you might not see it because the `<body>` also has no width restriction so it has a scrollbar on the bottom, thus hiding most of `.column-2` off screen (at least on Chrome).

Set `max-width: 50%` for `.column-2` and it will make `.column-2` actually 50% of it's parent, `.container`, and thus also 50% of the full body. Then you'll see scrollbars for the `.item-container` within the main window.

Answer (score 0):

Instated of `.item-container` provide `overflow` to parent class.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.column-1 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.column-2 {
  flex: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.6);
}

.item {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 20px;
  background: orange;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column-1">
    column 1
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <div class="item-container">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can't remove the width and it doesn't work when you do either

Comment: if you add the width then you will have horizontal window scroll. but still you will have scroll for item container.

Comment: do you need both scroll on .item-container. horizontal & vertical?

Comment: yes but the scroll is on the window, i need it on the .item-container only, I put the overflow: auto in .item-container because I want scrolling on that element

Comment: yes check my updated answer i got your desire output.

Comment: no it was the container of the element, see the other answer